# Built-in word list for AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, cpu-word

I want to make an AutoCompleteTextView in an app similar to a dictionary. I have found many word lists, the most accessible one being dicts in /usr/share/dict. The problem is the size of these words lists (around 1MB). Since I don not have a specific need and regular words in dictionary would suffice, I was hoping that there would be mechanism to use the word list that might be available in regular Android systems.

The question is: is there a way to use built-in word lists of Android OS, or should I bundle a 1MB extra word list file with my app?